# unconfigured table error with Capitalized table name

Tags: cassandra, cql

All my Cassandra column family names are capitalized (like `FunTable`, `SomeOtherTable`, etc.) -- I'm switching from the Thrift API to CQL, and whenever I make a query (like `SELECT * FROM FunTable`) it fails with `cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table funtable"`

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out, as I should have figured out from the table name being lower-cased in the error message, that CQL is case-insensitive, except inside quoted strings (similar to other SQL dialects). So the solution is just to put double quotes around the table name, like so: `SELECT * FROM "FunTable"`

If you are specifying the keyspace, you need to put the quote just around the table name, not around the combination of keyspace and table name, e.g. `SELECT * FROM good_keyspace."FunTable"`